# how to change default siteName and its physical path using msdeploy

Tags: msbuild, web-deployment, msdeploy

Here i'm trying to automate publish the package for a web application to publish IIS on a remote server.
Following things are done to make the package.

Publish.proj.xml file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Publish" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ProjectSolutionFile>Test.sln</ProjectSolutionFile>
        <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectToBuild Include="$(ProjectSolutionFile)">
            <Properties>DeployOnBuild=true;Configuration=$(Configuration)</Properties>
        </ProjectToBuild>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Publish">
        <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectToBuild)"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

If i pass this Publish.proj.xml file to msbuild. it'll build the solution and will create the package with below included things,

```
1. PackageTmp (folder)
2. Test.deploy.cmd
3. Test.deploy.SetParameters.xml
4. Test.SourceManifest.xml
5. Test.zip
```

Test.SetParameters.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parameters>
  <setParameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="Default Web Site/Test_deploy" />
</parameters>
```

Test.SourceManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sitemanifest>
  <IisApp path="C:\Release\Package\PackageTmp" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" />
  <setAcl path="C:\Release\Package\PackageTmp" setAclResourceType="Directory" />
  <setAcl path="C:\Release\Package\PackageTmp" setAclUser="anonymousAuthenticationUser" setAclResourceType="Directory" />
</sitemanifest>
```

Now, i'm trying to install this package in a remote server to publish the package using below command,

```
SalesCatalogue.deploy.cmd /y /M:https://RemoteServer:8172/MSDeploy.axd /u:"Test" /p:Test123 -allowUntrusted /A:basic
```

It has created new virtual directory in IIS under Default Web Site->Test_deploy and package files are deployed in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test_deploy folder.

My requirement is, **Virtual directory name, applicatio Pool, destination physical deployment path are should be configurable.** So that I can provide name whatever for virtual directory, can select desire application pool and can deploy in different path if required.

How can i achieve this? Any one can suggest me.

Thanks in advance.